# Event for Canceled Meeting?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, vsto

Is there Event to catch canceled meeting from outlook?

I have work around to check send folder and check meeting status, but is there any easier way ?

also

I need to get main meeting object because id saved there, and new cancellation make new item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a work around to monitor canceled meetings :

```
 private void _meetingFolder_BeforeItemMove(object item, Outlook.MAPIFolder moveTo, ref bool cancel) 
 {  
     if (item is Outlook.AppointmentItem appointmentItem)
     {
         // some code 
     }
     else if (item is Outlook.MeetingItem meeting)
     {
         // some code 
     }
 }
```